# Preserving order while iterating over pandas GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

`pandas.groupby()` function can be made to sort the result by the grouping key (and does so by default). However, `DataFrameGroupBy.groups` is a `dict`, which does not preserve ordering of the keys. So, my question is, how is it ensured that the order is preserved when I iterate over the groups, like

```
dfg = df.groupby('some_key')
for name in dfg.groups:
    <do useful stuff>
```

In other words, how can `dfg.groups.keys()` be sorted if `dfg.groups` is just a `dict`?

Comment: you should just be able to iterate over `dfg` (i.e., `for name, group in dfg:...`)

Comment: Sample data is always welcome, along with expected result.